# Prepare custom tag list with 'or not' is not working

Tags: support, tag-filters

I am creating a custom filter tag list,

```
java-8 or java-7 or java-11 or java not android not swing not eclipse not selenium
```

But it's not working for the *not* case. How can I do that?

```
(java-8 or java-7 or java-11 or java) not (android or swing or eclipse or selenium )
```

Example: Here I am doing `not spring` question, but it still came in the result:

[image: Example]

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8+or+java-7+or+java-11+or+java+-android+-swing+-eclipse+-selenium) working?

Comment: @ahmedus Yes it's working , but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-stream+or+java-9+or+java-time+or+java-8+or+java-7+or+java-11+or+java+or+arraylist+-android+-swing+-eclipse+-selenium) is not working, still android question came but in shadow form

Comment: @Eklavya _"still android question came but in shadow form"_ If these carry one of your positive tags, that's normal and by design.

Comment: If you mean it happens after clicking _"1 question with new activity"_, I'm able to reproduce it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ check the url I not doing minus(not) android tag still comes

Comment: @ahmedus try this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20or%20java-time%20-android) are you still see android tagged question ?

Comment: I don't see until I click _"1 question with new activity"_. As @πάνταῥεῖ commented, this behavior appears to be known.

Comment: @ahmedus I added a picture for proof and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java%20or%20java-time%20-spring) you can check spring tagged question came

Comment: I just suggested an edit with a similar screenshot. :) Certainly I see it, but not right after a search. I see only if a new question is received.

Comment: @ahmedus You can click the link of previous comment and search on browser `Rest tamplate 400 null - bad request` (as its not newly received)

Comment: Crystal clear now.